# Is there a way to leave an empty DataTable column through the aoColumns/mData?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable, which is generated and populated through the aoColumns and mData

```
var dtable = $('.ssdatatable').DataTable({
    //list of datatable properties
    ,
    "aoColumns":[
        { "mData": "parameter" },
        //other columns
    ]//and other stuff
```

Currently I am adding an extra first column to make it into a "multiple checkbox row select".

So I added an extra `<th></th>` at the beginning (left the column name blank), and modified script file like following:

```
var dtable = $('.ssdatatable').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets: 0
        }],
    "select": { style: 'multi', selector: 'td:first-child' },
    //list of datatable properties
    ,
    "aoColumns":[
        { "mData": "parameter" },
        //other columns
    ]//and other stuff
```

However, since I left aoColumns section untouched, all datas were moved by one column to the left, starting with empty column. I did additional research to prevent that, and tried using `"mData": null`. While it prevented an error, and turned the first column into a row of checkboxes like I wanted, these checkboxes were overflowed with `[object Object]` text. I tried using `"mData": " "`, but it throws an error of empty source.

**Is there a way to leave a column empty while using aoColumns/mData combination?**

Comment: did you try playing around with the `render` option in the first column? maybe returning an empty string in the render function or building the checkboxes there.

Comment: maybe `nbsp;` instead of ` ` would fool it...

Comment: @dandavis Just tried it, `"mData": '&nbsp'`, returns error of unknown parameter nbsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not an ideal solution, but I managed to get it working. For that, I have created a source inside the controller like

```
q.Select(p=> new {Checkbox = "", and other stuff})
```

and in Javascript I simply declared Checkbox as a source of the first mData

```
"mData": "Checkbox"
```

And voila! All unnecessary text is gone now.